# Proof that isomorphic graphs must have the same number of vertices

Tags: graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

An isomorphism of graphs G and H is a bijection between the vertex sets of G and H. So I know that from definition of a bijection number of vertices must be the same, but how to describe it offically on a test ?

Comment: So, an information that "according to the bijection definition" is enough ?

Comment: The formal mathematical notion of two sets having "the same number" is exactly that a bijection between the two sets exists.  If you want a fancier mathematical term, say the two sets have "equal cardinality".

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You just proved it.

Anyway, this is a special case of a more general phenomenon, namely that:

- functors preserve isomorphisms
- hence functors preserve isomorphicness.

In this case, we're talking about the underlying set functor $$U : \mathbf{Grph} \rightarrow \mathbf{Set}.$$